# How to show Activity over lock screen in 4.2 jellybean while in sleep mode

Tags: android

i have implemented keyguard.wakelock to show activity on lock-screen(sleep mode) but 
it show activity only in android version 2.2 and get crashed on above 2.3 version and some time on version 2.2 it show activity for few sec and then dis-appear over lock screen .so plz guide me to obtain this scenario working on every Android version .
here is the code i have used .

KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

```
boolean iskeyguardopen =km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();

    //KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock("IN");
Log.v("check key guard is enabled or not",""+km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode());


        //setContentView(R.layout.customactivitypop);
        count=1;
    kl = km.newKeyguardLock("Taxi");
    kl.disableKeyguard();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl=pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK  , "My_App");
    wl.acquire();


    wl.release();
```

Thank all.

Comment: DayDream. Its new and only above 4.1